# Setting the line length in R

Tags: r, stata

[Google R style](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-r-style.html#linelength) guide suggests line length of maximum 80 characters. I was wondering how do I set the line length in `R`. In `stata` this is done as:

```
set linesize 80
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is:

```
options()$width
```

what you want?

You can set it like:

```
options(width=80)
```

Comment: Note this sets the width of (most of) the output. Line width of input will be based on whatever editor/IDE you are using.

Comment: Note that if you use the RStudio IDE, this option seems to be dynamically modified each time you resize the IDE window.